# How to import html and insert onto a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, polymer

I would like to insert a html file into another div in a html file. I am not proficient to javascript and I come with this idea.

```
<head>
    <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html" />
    <link rel="import" id="note-import-01" href="some.html" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="notes">
    <div id="blocker"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var link = document.querySelector('#note-import-01');
        var content = link.importNode;
        parent.insertBefore(content);
    </script>
</div>
</body>
```

However, it does not appear what I want. For example, the div with id blocker did not include the page content. *Sorry, In here I mean the some.html at line 3.*

Note that

- I have included polymer but the file path to polymer depends on you
- I know that I have to upload the parent and component pages on server, but I done this for dozen of times so, I need some help.

Comment: Are you trying to use Polymer to insert another html file? Or jQuery? If it's Polymer, you need to create an element, or use auto-binding templates.

Comment: @anthony It is an html file

Comment: I understand it's an html file. But, I'm trying to understand if you're trying to use Polymer to do it, or jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try loading your html file `some.html` into your current page used the jQuery `.load()` method.

The below solution has a anchor tag `a` which has a `click` event handler and inside the handler the local html page `some.html` is loaded.

**JS Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#aUrl').hide();
      $('#divPage').load(this.href); 
 });
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="divPage"></div>
  <a href="http://lesson8.blogspot.in/2012/06/bind-gridview-using-jquery.html" id="aUrl">Load Page</a>
```

**Live Demo @ JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/dVPQw/740/**

*Note: The above jsfiddle is not allowing to load the remote resource, but in your case the local resource will be loaded perfectly*

Comment: I did not ask for to click to the page, because I don't think readers like clicking too much.

Comment: Apology, didnt see that. now it would load automatically. http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/dVPQw/740/

Comment: Your solution works, but I changed a little bit to avoid the <a>. If one don't mind see psssix.shyjohn.net/tp/matter-model-ideal-gases.html

Comment: yeah that should fine, since the solution was to showcase the generic fix, so you can modify as per your requirement. also i see some css issue with the white background around the table at the end of your page,you need to fix that as well

Answer (score 0):

Add jQuery to the page and then use this with the proper URL in place of the example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery("#blocker").load("yourURLHere");
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's `load`

```
$("#blocker").load("polymer/polymer.html");
```

Or with plain javascript

```
var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'polymer/polymer.html', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200)                
        document.getElementById('blocker').innerHTML= this.responseText;
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean the polymer. It is already loaded in my page successfully.

Comment: Yeah i thought you were loading polymer.html.. You can load any file as long it's from the same server

Comment: Weird, I end up a loop of loading the parent page(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with HTMLImports like so:

```
<pre id="notes"></pre>

<script>
  function importLoaded(link, slctr) {
    document.querySelector(slctr).appendChild(link.import.body);
  }
</script>

<link href="polymer/bower.json" rel="import" onload="importLoaded(this, '#notes')">
```